# Why does DRF TemplateHTMLRenderer require different serializer output than other serializers?

Tags: django-rest-framework

In order to get custom HTML output for my serializers, I am starting with [TemplateHTMLRenderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/).

However, just setting renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer] in my ViewSet yields an error because the renderer requires data to be a dict, not a ReturnList.

Code:

```
class ValidatedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)  # so that it shows at all

    class Meta:
        model = Validated
        exclude = ()


class ValidatedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]

    queryset = Validated.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ValidatedSerializer

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return ['examples/validated_list.html']
        return ['examples/validated.html']
```

WHY is this so? I mean, I'm currently "solving" this issue by simply doing this:

```
class MyTemplateHTMLRenderer(TemplateHTMLRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        if isinstance(data, ReturnList):
            data = dict(data=data,
                        serializer=data.serializer.child
                        if isinstance(data.serializer, serializers.ListSerializer) else data.serializer)
        return super().render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

But why doesn't DRF already do this? Am I using TemplateHTMLRenderer in a way that was not intended?